# checks whether a string is a valid password

Tags: c#, string, passwords

This is my homework ,edited it:

Some websites impose certain rules for passwords. Write a function that checks whether a string is a valid password. Suppose the password rules are as follows:

- A password must have at least eight characters.
- A password consists of only letters and digits.
- A password must contain at least two digits.

Write a C# program that prompts the user to enter a password and displays Valid Password if the rules are followed or Invalid Password otherwise

This is what i have done for now :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Password: ");
        String password = Console.ReadLine();

        if (isValid(password))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Valid Password");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Password");
        }
    }

    public static bool isValid(String password)
    {
        if (password.Length < 8)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            char c;
            int count = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < password.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                c = password[i];
                if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else if (Char.IsDigit(c))
                {
                    count++;
                    if (count < 2)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

But there is a problem i cant find

Comment: The test for count should be executed after exiting the for...loop

Comment: whats the problem you can't find?

Comment: @Steve Good find, that problem causes the for-loop to exit the first time it finds a digit in the input string. I'd add that as an answer.

Comment: "It doesn't work." Is not a good problem statement.

Comment: Thanks @RonBeyer but being this an homework I will let the poster try it by itself. This will be more useful than writing the code for him

Comment: @Steve The answer doesn't have to include the code :)

Comment: a regex is also a solution. `"(?=^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$)(?=.*\d.*\d)"`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I'm guessing if he's having trouble with `if` placement, a regex isn't going to make life any easier.

Comment: @Steve It is true. ;)

Comment: @RonBeyer probably. but maybe he will understand how life can be easier! maybe in future ;)

Comment: If we want to make life confusing, this is also equivalent to the `isValid` function: `return password.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit) && password.Count(char.IsDigit) >= 2 && password.Length >= 8;`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more what you're looking for:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Password: ");
        var password = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(IsValid(password) ? "Valid Password" : "Invalid Password");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static bool IsValid(string password)
    {
        var charactersInPassword = password.ToCharArray();
        if (charactersInPassword.Length < 8) return false;
        if (charactersInPassword.Any(character => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(character)))
            return false;

        var numberOfDigits = charactersInPassword.Count(char.IsDigit);
        return numberOfDigits >= 2;
    }
```

I'd suggest getting yourself a good code analysis tool if you're interested in programming.  I don't know any developers without something like Resharper/Productivity power tools or whatever.  It will help you write better code with less redundancy.  It's also better to use the inbuilt .net functionality for strings etc (like ToCharArray).  You've probably been taught to use the :

```
for (int i = 0; i < password.Length - 1; i++)
```

It's a long and annoying way to write something that could be written clearer and easier such as:

```
foreach (var characterInPassword in password.ToCharArray())
```

Also, I know you're not writing in Python, but this is worth a read:  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ .  It's a quick read and it gets you in the right state of mind when writing code.